# How many spells can a Cleric prepare?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, cleric

To my understanding, in Pathfinder, I have all Cleric spells available to me but in order to use them I have to prepare them first.

- How many can I prepare?
- Does it depend on my spell slots or can I prepare all of them but cast only 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each day, you can prepare a total number of spells as listed in the table, plus any bonus spells you get for a high Wisdom score.

For example, a 1st-level cleric with 18 Wisdom: the table says 1+1 first-level spell slots, which is to say 1 from the cleric list and 1 from one of his domains. He also gets a bonus first-level slot from his high Wisdom. So, ignoring his domain spell slot, he can prepare two spells that day.

That means he can prepare, for example, 1 use each of *divine favor* and *magic weapon*. Or he could prepare 2 uses of *divine favor*, or 2 uses of *magic weapon*. And the next day, it’s the same deal but could be any cleric spell or pair of cleric spells. But he has to choose how many of each to prepare each day.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Eh, I left out the domain spell but that was unclear. I'll mention explicitly what I was doing.

Comment: so the number of prepared spells is infact limited by the number of available spell slots excluding the ones reserved for domain spells.
also i had no idea that the +1 slot depicted on the table was the domain spell slot.

Comment: @NoPuhi For a prepared caster, a “spell slot” is just a place to put a “prepared spell,” so yes, you need a spell slot for each spell you want to prepare, and you have no ability to use a spell slot without preparing something in it first.

Comment: @No Puhi It sounds to me like you're using 5e D&D terminology for spellcasting (i.e. the term slots - although I see now that PF uses that term too, it's not as common). Try having a read of the Divine spellcasting rules at http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Preparing-Divine-Spells